# How to get to the head node of a linked list?

Tags: python, linked-list

I am trying to write a function that finds the union of two linked lists. Although, I can't seem to work it out. I wrote something like this, yet the issue with that is that the second loop only traverses the linked list `b` once and then it won't come back to the start. I tried to somehow save the first item of the list `b` in some other variable and then change current Node to the first one, once second loop finishes. But it always is an integer. Can you please point me guys in some way? Thanks. Current version of my code is

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, x, next):
        self.x = x
        self.next = next

def union(a,b):
    while a != None:
        match = False
        while b != None:
            if a.x == b.x:
                match = True
            b = b.next
        if match == False:
            a.x = a.next
        a = a.next
    return a
```

Comment: You need to save a reference to the original values of `a` and `b` before you go into your loop. Once you assign to `a` or `b`, you lose your reference inside the function to the original head of the list.

Comment: You also need to consider if `union` should modify either original list, or build a *new* list containing the values from `a` and `b`.

Comment: @chepner Yes, I have tried to save it somehow using something like ```head = b``` and then later refer to it when the inner loop finishes as ```b = head``` but I could execute it, while the ```head``` variable is integer, not Note element.